# How to set a breakpoint with lldb + mono

Tags: debugging, mono, lldb

I have the following C# program (test.cs) which I want to debug:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Hello, World!" );
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(123);
        list.Add(234);
        list.Add(345);
        list.Add(456);
        int number = 4;
        ++number;
        Console.WriteLine(" number " + number); // <--- L:16 I want to set a breakpoint here :)
        Console.WriteLine("Number of elements" + list.Count);
        foreach (Object obj in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + obj);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Bye");
    }
}
```

And below is the debug session using **lldb** and **mono** (I am in OSX). I can start the session and run the program however I am not able to setup any breakpoint. I guess that when using mono as the executable file things are different. How can I achieve this?

```
$ mcs -debug test.cs
$ lldb 
(lldb) target create mono
Current executable set to 'mono' (i386).
(lldb) b test.cs:16
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
(lldb) run --debug test.exe 
Process 15191 launched: '/usr/bin/mono' (i386)
Hello, World!
 number 5
Number of elements4
 123
 234
 345
 456
Bye
Process 15191 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000) 
(lldb)
```

I've tried with GBD as [this old guide suggests](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging#Debugging_with_GDB) but it is worse, apparently there is [something broken in mono in OSX](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15090) that makes it impossible to debug unless the soft debugger is used (which is exactly what I want to avoid. MonoDevelop debugger is really really unstable/unreliable/slow). This is [what I have tried with GBD](https://gist.github.com/nacho4d/14344cc175c159e6ed0d). No luck at all.

And help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems like something that would be heavily influenced by the way Mono's execution environment works. Is your process loaded as a dylib inside of mono? Is mono doing JIT compilation of the .net byte code? Assuming the former, is there debug information in DWARF format for your test.exe?

Comment: I think is it the later. JIT is the default. When I did `mcs -debug test.cs` in addition to test.exe also test.exe.mdb was created. This is meant to be consumed in a debug session. I wonder how can I use such file in lldb

Comment: That depends on what the MDB format is.. if it's a proprietary Microsoft format, it's highly unlikely that LLDB will have a decoder for it. If OTOH, it's an open source format, someone motivated enough could write a decoder for it.

Comment: That still won't give you the full experience though.. for instance, LLDB has no understanding of C# as a language to write expressions in, so you will find yourself severely limited in that regard. Also, LLDB does not understand .net types - you would have to represent types coming out of MDB debug info as Clang types as things stand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't `mono` the interpreter for your language and `test.exe` the binary?  lldb only knows about `mono` -- any breakpoints you try to set would be in the `mono` interpreter.  e.g. if you were debugging an issue with `mono` itself.

This is a unique enough environment that you'll need to do a little analysis to understand what lldb sees.  What do you get for

```
(lldb) image list test.exe
```

?  Of course if you do

```
(lldb) im li mono
```

You'll see mono listed -- because that's a binary that lldb knows about.  (you can use plain `image list` aka `im li` to see all the binaries that lldb knows)

You can ask lldb to list all of the line table entries based on a source filename with a command line

```
(lldb) target modules dump line-table test.cs
```

if lldb has any debug information for a `test.cs`, you'll see a line table.  Without a line table, file and line breakpoints (`b test.cs:16`) won't work.

For what it's worth, I don't think trying to use lldb (or gdb) to debug your C# program will work.  You'll probably need to use some facility of the mono runtime itself to set breakpoints and examine program state.

Comment: Thanks Jason, Indeed I am truing to debug test.exe but attaching mono, so I dont see anything for `im li test.exe` but i do see mono in `im li mono`.  So it seems i am trying to do something impossible since llvm knows nothing about test.exe

Comment: I forgot to mention that compiling like `mcs -debug test.cs` makes also the file test.exe.mdb which according to the docs it is debbugable with gdb, so I assumed it was debbugable with lldb too. The docs mention runtime functions to convert resove memomy addresses into function names, etc. http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging#Debugging_with_GDB . I actually could call `mono_pmip` from Xcode while debbuging a cpp pluging that was used by a c# application. so I still hope i can use lldb or at leadt gdb instead of monodebbuger :)

Comment: Yeah, the way they make it work with gdb is to define a bunch of gdb commands that call into mono to do address to function name mapping and such.  There's a section on that web page for debugging with lldb.  I didn't try the code they had on the page, but it looks reasonable.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Oh!!, Last time I checked that page, there wasn't that part. That is new: `document.lastModified "02/26/2014 06:05:04" `. I will check it at home later! :-)